# Dell laptop weird display after hard reboot

Tags: display, dell-vostro

Dell laptop display issue

I was watching a streaming video on my laptop and it stopped responding, I did a hard reboot since Ctrl-Alt-del also didn't help.

On reboot, there's no display, I can see hard drive activity and hear the Windows startup sound, but there a lot of lines on the screen (which change in color, during the boot and window startup process) and nothing else.

The laptop is a Dell Vostro 14" with Intel Dual Core processor,2 GB RAM and a nvidia Graphics Card. It's running Windows Vista. The laptop is 2 years old. I haven't had any problems with the display before.

I didn't come across a similar issue on a Google search and hence looking for an answer here.

Comment: Does it display the BIOS startup screen correctly, or is it garbage from the start?

Comment: Garbage from start

Comment: I tried connecting a Dell LCD Monitor to the laptop. I am able to switch to the external display, but it says: Analog Input, Cannot display this video mode.

Comment: Interesting I reconnected the external display and was able to get something. quite similar to http://media.photobucket.com/image/dell%20e1705%20laptop%20nvidia%20artifacts/ray_freeze/8800gtx_video_artifact_02.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact [DELL support](http://support.dell.com/).

Article: "[Dell issues update for...graphics chip glitch](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13924_3-10000353-64.html)" According to the article, Vostro 1400 is on the list. This became public over a year ago. Hopefully your system is still covered.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this a little while back.
Some more details: http://en.community.dell.com/blogs/direct2dell/archive/2008/09/12/nvidia-gpu-update-limited-warranty-enhancement-details.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

Unfortunately, I am 15 days out of the warranty, I purchased the system on Sept 3 2007 and hit the problem on Sept 28, and they online chat person said it will cost me $750+ to get the laptop repaired now

Comment: That stinks. For $750 you could get a brand new laptop.

Comment: well, a new Dell Vostro costs about $550. They quoted $250 for LCD + $515 for Mobo as they have to change both to get the issue resolved.