# Laptop monitor goes black under intense graphics

Tags: laptop, display, graphics-card, integrated-graphics

I have a dell inspiron 1520 with a nvidia GeForce 8600M GT video card. I have Windows 7 professional as an operating system.

Yesterday when I was using it the screen started to somewhat flicker then go completely black. I restarted it and in the boot screen everything seems fine, when I entered the login screen it became flickery again, and when I logged in, when a couple of windows popped up it went black again. I hooked it up to a tft monitor and the monitor works fine, and did some more tests that confirmed that under higher graphics causes the laptop monitor to go black.

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took the laptop to the store where I bought it from since it was still under warranty.. Apparently there was a fault with the monitor, had it replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be related to this question [Dell laptop weird display after hard reboot](https://superuser.com/questions/48306/dell-laptop-weird-display-after-hard-reboot).

Answer (score 0):

[Nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) now releases updated drivers to the public.  You don't have to go through the manufacturer anymore.

I would check to make sure you have a current driver.

If that doesn't help you may have a bad or failing video card.